# 'ckeditor4-react' and 'HTML5 video' plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I want to add [html5video plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/html5video#) to my CKEditor component. I use `"ckeditor4-react": "^1.1.0"` and this is my component:

```
import React, { useState, FunctionComponent }   from "react";
import CKEditor                                 from "ckeditor4-react";

export interface CreateNewArticleProps {}

const CreateNewArticle: FunctionComponent<CreateNewArticleProps> = () => {
    const [articleFormData, setArticleFormData] = useState({
        articleBody: "",
    });

    const ckeditorConfig = {
        extraPlugins: "justify, colorbutton, font",
    };
    const ckeditorDataChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setArticleFormData({
            ...articleFormData,
            articleBody: event.editor.getData(),
        });
    };

    return (
        <CKEditor
            type="classic"
            config={ckeditorConfig}
            data={articleFormData.articleBody}
            onChange={ckeditorDataChangeHandler}
        />
    );
};
export default CreateNewArticle;
```

I don't have any idea about how to add the `html5video plugin` to CKEditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommended using [tiny editor](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react) instead of Ckeditor. It is very simple for customization, especially for inserting video tag.

Answer (score 0):

The CKEditor 4 React component assumes that CKEditor is loaded before creating any CKeditor components. This way you can pass it [URL to custom build of CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_react.html#customizing-ckeditor-preset-or-version) with every needed plugin:

```
CKEditor.editorUrl = 'https://your-website.example/ckeditor/ckeditor.js';
```

To load plugins into the editor's instance, [pass ***config*** prop to the component](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_react.html#changing-editor-configuration):

```
    <CKEditor
    config={ {
        extraPlugins: 'extra,plugins'
    } }
/>
```

Comment: Your answer is not related to my question. I'm looking for how to add html5video plugin to my CKEditor component.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this :

1. download and add below plugin to your ckeditor :
   http://martinezdelizarrondo.com/ckplugins/video1.3.zip
2. add plugin name to ckeditor config like :

   config.extraPlugins = 'video';
3. refresh page and you must see video icon in ckeditor toolbar.

Done